# Rails 3 + Devise: user_signed_in? for a different user in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm building an app where I want to add an online status for a given user.

I know that Devise has a method user_signed_in? built in to check if the user who is using the app is signed in or not. But when I try to use it for a different user like this:

```
user_signed_in?(user)

user.user_signed_in?
```

I obviously get an undefined method error.

Does Devise have a method for this or do I have to write my own?
One approach was to store the online status of a given user in the user model.
What's the best solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the author of Devise, but from what I can tell of Warden / Devise neither keep track of who is logged in.

The problem with having an is_online column in the User table is that it is difficult to see who is active on the website.  I would add a column to your User model called last_seen as a date-time, and update that with Devise every time the user requests a page.  You could then easily add a User.online_count method or also see if a user has been seen at the website in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: I could also combine the two by making an online, away and offline status. Because I don't like the idea of declaring an user as "offline" when he hasn't been active for a period of time.

Comment: I guess I have to store everything in the database.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it just occurred to me that you might be able to accomplish this with a before_filter.

Comment: you mean the last request part? Not sure ... I would probably have to add an before_filter in ALL controllers. Or would it be enough to just add one to the application controller?

Comment: I'm guessing that if you before_filter on current_user method that'd be enough, so long as you've got something in your template that calls it (eg, a menu item that only shows up for logged in users).

Comment: It's worth pointing out, for those who come across this answer, that updating the user table every time they send a request is an awful lot of unnecessary write-load on your database. With a popular website that's going to break horribly.  Then again, if you weren't already aware of this issue, you probably won't have that problem anyway.

Comment: I agree with @Benson. Honestly you best and smartest way is to go with a websockets integration, either custom built or something like Pusher. This way, either would be able to let the browser know if that resource is listening to a specified channel (maybe called logged in or something generic) or not and do what you want. Obviously this is through JS and not the ruby side. So you'd need to make some kind of ajax call to do whatever it is you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 18):

I have used Devise on my applications and experienced some of the same problems as you when I first began working with it.  You are merely using the helper methods incorrectly.  If you'd like to check if the current user has a session and is signed in, you use the helper as such:

```
if user_signed_in?
```

which is essentially the same statement as:

```
if !current_user.nil? && current_user.signed_in
```

If you'd like to check if a user object is signed in, then you call this: (where *user* is a User Model Object)

```
if user.signed_in?
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `devise_for :user` in your routes.rb.