# how to access column using devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I added the following columns using a new migration as follows:

```
class AddDetailsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :userNum, :integer
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_column :users, :fname, :string
    add_column :users, :surname, :string
    add_column :users, :isTeacher, :boolean, :default => false


  end
end
```

Now in the application.html.erb I want to do something like this which is trying to show button only when the user is actually a teacher :

```
<% if @user.isTeacher? %>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <%= button_to(etc ..) %>
                    </div>
<% end %>
```

but the problem is that I get the following error message:

> undefined method `isTeacher?' for nil:NilClass

How to fix this problem ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: @SebastianPalma I get the same error !

Comment: if @user is nil verify if in your controller @ user is successfully setted.

Comment: Check in the controller the value of `@user`, it should be a single User object.

Comment: @adcosta can u explain more please or give an example ? Thanks

Comment: @SebastianPalma I don't have it. How to add it ?

Comment: normally devise gives you a var to use for this. it's current_user. You can use current_user.isTeacher

Comment: @adcosta that solved the problem, thanks! If u want add it as an answer so that other will benefit from it and you and I get some points from it too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise have helpers to give your views (and controllers) access to your user device model ([devise helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)).

In your case you can use current_user.isTeacher

Answer (score 2):

Devise provide you a helper method named `current_your_devise_model_name` if your devise model is user then `current_user`, if your devise model is admin then `current_admin`. In your case you do not have any value in @user. You basically need to update your if condition. I suppose you need to display this button when user is login and is a teacher. So change your code a bit

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.isTeacher? %>
    <div class="buttons">
       <%= button_to(etc ..) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Your code is in `application.html.erb` layout which means it will be executed in those pages where user is not login and is using same layout. For more user login methods you should check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939231/3759158) as we do not know which rails version you are currently working on.